# An error occured please run the package manager from the right click menu

Tags: 13.10, package-management, update-manager, software-updater

I am facing some issue my ubuntu bar was showing some triangle with ! sign and I tried to find out some solution and by mistake i deleted /etc/apt/sources.list I tried to search for some solution but got nothing now sign look like as shown in the link image. Could anyone help me out to find the solution I am using ubuntu 13.10.

Current bar:- http://screencloud.net/v/g7lr

Could any one help me thanx in advance and now even my update manager is not working i think I need to reinstall the ubuntu please suggest if any solution I am having lots of configuration on my system.

I get the following  when running `sudo apt get update`

```
Err ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Sources 404 Not Found Err ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages 404 Not Found
Err ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages 404 Not Found 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_IN Ign ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main  
Translation-en Fetched 748 kB in 3min 14s (3,851 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch packages.medibuntu.org/dists/saucy/InRelease 
W: Failed to fetch packages.medibuntu.org/dists/saucy/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'packages.medibuntu.org' 
W: Failed to fetch extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/sauscy/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found 
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/… 404 Not Found
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/… 404 Not Found
```

Comment: whats wrong in the image??

Comment: The "Ing"(ignore) is just a info flag, it is normal for them(translations) to be ignored. 404 errors mean that the site is not being found(either because you are not getting to the internet/not connected) but I see one typo that will cause a 404 for one source..."extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ **sauscy** /main/source/Sources" "saucy" is misspelled as "sauscy"

Comment: I also see that you have medibuntu sources enabled, these have been taken down, so they will always cause a 404 error

Comment: I removed medibuntu from the list and also changed sauscy to saucy now what should i do after this?

Comment: Now if i run sudo apt-get update it is showing me some error:- Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found

Answer (score 1):

as you said you have deleted the sources.list you can regenerate it.

Open http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and  fill the form, Finally it will give you source links and paste them in sources.list file with

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then save and close.

Then try again.